# Barchart X-Axis is getting hidden when bringing to bottom in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, axis-labels

I ma shifting the X-Axis to bottom, it is not visible and only coming when its on the bar chart. There is some svg area problem which I ma not able to find out. how to shift the barchart a bit upwards so that X=Axis labeling could be accommodated.

Here is the fiddle link [Working but X-Axis Label is on the Top](https://jsfiddle.net/hawkeye15/gwwt8tts/)

```
                     a = 100;
                     b = 150;
                     c = 103;
                     dataset= [a,b,c];
                     var w = 500;
                      var h = 250;
                      var barPadding = 1;
                      var marginleft = 1;
                      var margintop =1; 
                      var marginbottom =15;
                      margin  = {top:1, right:10, bottom:1, left:1};  
                   colors = ["#e41a1c",  "#377eb8", "#4daf4a"];
                       h = h ;

            var category= ['A', 'B', 'C'];

                    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
                        .domain(category)
                        .rangeRoundBands([0, w]);



                    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                        .scale(x)
                        .orient("bottom")
                        .ticks(0);;



                 //Create SVG element
                      var svg = d3.select("#hello")
                      .append("svg")
                      .attr("width", w )
                      .attr("height", h )
                      .append("g")
                      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


                     svg.append("g")
                      .attr("class", "x axis")
                      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
                      .call(xAxis);

                  // GENERATING RECTANGLES AND MAKING BAR CHART

                     svg.selectAll("rect")
                     .data(dataset)
                     .enter()
                     .append("rect")

                     .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                          return i * (w / dataset.length);
                      })
                     .attr("y", function(d) {
                          return h - (d*1.5) ;
                     })
                     .attr("width", w / dataset.length - barPadding)
                     .attr("height", function(d) {
                          return (d*2 );
                     })

                     .attr("fill", function(d,i) {
                           return colors[i];
              //       .attr("fill", function(d) {
              //            return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d * 10) + ")";
                      });

                     var x_Axis = svg.append('g')
                          .attr('class','xnewaxis')
                          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (20) + ")")
                          .call(xAxis)
                          .selectAll("text")  
                              .style("text-anchor", "start")
                              .attr("dx", "-2.5em")
                              .attr("dy", ".5em")
                              .attr("transform", "rotate(-15)" );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has **several** problems:

- two different datasets for the bars;
- lacks an ordinal scale for positioning the bars (actually, there is one, which you don't use);
- lacks a linear scale for the bars values;
- calls `xAxis` twice, with different translations;

But, for solving the axis problem, you just need to translate it correctly:

```
 var x_Axis = svg.append('g')
     .attr('class','xnewaxis')
     .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h- 30) + ")")
    //30 here is the padding from the bottom of the SVG
```

Here is your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gfwo0br9/

The bars are still showing up behind the axis (actually, the bars are going way below the end of the SVG itself). To fix that, you'll have to draw the bars properly (with a scale setting the range and the domains).

Comment: Replacing h-30 with h leads to invisibility of axis. I don't want it to overlap on the bar chart.

Comment: Think of what you're doing using just `h`: you want the code to render something *after* the limit of the SVG. How is this going to work?

Comment: Yes but adding excess height or subtracting from the height in svg is also not working.

Comment: Of course it is working, just look at the fiddle: the axis is there.

Comment: Axis is there but I want it to be at the bottom that means I will have to shift the base of bar-chart by some amount so that axis remain there in the svg, which I am unable to do.

Comment: Read my answer again. To move the bars up and have an proper padding you'll have to draw the bars correctly. That involves a linear scale and a proper positioning. Right now, your bars are going *below* the end of the SVG. And you can set `h = 500`, `h=1000` or any other value, it will make no difference.

Comment: So you mean to say in y-axis too, I have to do linear scaling?

Comment: Yes. This, for instance, is a basic example of using an linear scale: https://jsfiddle.net/fzm1mhj9/

Comment: No worries. Also, read about how to use an ordinal scale. Right now, your bars are not using any scale for the x position.